# CSS BEM - Convention for common class

Tags: css, bem

I'm trying to refactor our styles with BEM convention. On our page, we got some elements which are written `bold`.

Let's say we got a `startpage` and a `detailpage`. Both pages contains some text elements. Often this elements has an extra class, which only contains

```
.block__element {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
.block__element--modifier {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

To avoid unneccessary code duplication, I'm asking myself how to refactor this best. Is it a good approach to define one common element (maybe in my main `style.css`)

```
.text--bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

which I can use in all places where texts needs to be set bold? Or is there a better solution?

**EDIT:**
I think [mixes](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#modifiers) are the way to go. So as far as i understood I need to create a mix `text--bold` and apply it to every affected text element?

Comment: Not directly an answer for your question but have you looked at BEMIT? (https://csswizardry.com/2015/08/bemit-taking-the-bem-naming-convention-a-step-further/) It uses prefixes, for instance, you can use a utility-class and name it `.u-text-bold` and keep it in a file only for text. And then use the class for all text that should be bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

**BEM guidelines on DRY : https://cssguidelin.es/#dry**

Basically, you should not force yourself to hunt duplicated lines of code. But if a specific case is happening more than once, you can make use of a mixin.

```
@mixin my-web-font() {
  font-family: "My Web Font", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  @include my-web-font();
}

[...]

.page-title {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  @include my-web-font();
}

[...]

  .user-profile__title {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    @include my-web-font();
  }
```

This is clearer for your code to write, but will actually compile as duplicated lines. So my answer below still makes sense.

---

IMHO, I disagree with @Kareem Dabbeet's answer.

**I'm no BEM expert**, but if you want to follow the exact convention, your bold text should stay a modifier of the element it is tied to.
So you should get something like

```
.block__element--bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.otherBLock__element--bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Even though, I myself use a lot of reusable classes, the convention says to organize your code according to your blocks/elements structure. There is no mention of some global utilities classes.

However, you're right, depending on the use case, it can lead to code duplication. But BEM is all about some sort of separation of concerns. **You should read and write your css focusing only on the block/element it is tied and not looking elsewhere.** So it makes sense.

**Using classes that are not tied to any block or element alongside BEM will likely risk you to create conflicts in the long run.**

Comment: I agree with this approach. Every block should be as much independent as he can. However, this is not always possible. Lets look at your example with `font-family`. The font should be the same over each block, no matter where it is placed. So it depends on each single attribute, if it should be treated as a mixin or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's A Good idea.

The Main Goal from wtite in BEM Style is that:

### everything **is a class** and nothing is **nested**.

So it's legal to define as much useful classes as you want:

Examples:

```
.bold { font-weight: bold}
.bolder { font-weight: bolder }
.red { color: red}
.redbg {background-color: red}
.nomargin { margin: 0}
```

And So on,

For sure, you can also modify specific element styles by using:

```
.component--blue {
   color: blue;
}
```

and append this class to any element inside the abstract `component` block

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand BEM, you separate *styles* and *semantics*. *Semantics* are expressed with css classes (`.button--emphasized`), whereas *styles* are expressed with actual css (`font-weight: bold`). This means you leave out actual styles from css classes as much as possible (no class `.bold`), but instead ask yourself *why is it bold?* and express that with css:

```
.button--emphasized,
.text--headline,
.input--required {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

You still write the `font-weight: bold` only once (and don't repeat yourself). But if (for whatever reason) you decide that emphasized buttons should not be bold any more, you don't have to change all occurrences of `.bold` in a `.button` element in all html/component files. You then just have to remove the `.button--emphasized` from the `font-weight: bold` list.

Comment: With this approach I need to split my definitions for a single block into multiple files. I think it would be better to keep all elements and modifier for a certain block in one single file.

Comment: If you use a css preprocessor, you can leverage that to your advantage and e.g. have a never used/"abstract" `.element--bold{font-weight:bold} ` css that you then extend in multiple files like (sass) `.button--emphasized{@extend .element--bold;}` and `.text--headline{@extend .element--bold}`. My main point is that it proved helpful to me to not have actual style in the css classes, because then you can change the actual style without changing the html.